# python xml2dict complex xml

Tags: python, xml, xmltodict

I have a huge and complex xml document that I wanted to parse into a dictionary (and later on into a db with sqlalchemy). I want to use [xmltodict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmltodict) for this task.
However, it seems that xmltodict cannot parse deeply nested xml directly.

My MWE:

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:tag-1>
    <ns2:tag-2 attrib1="value" attrib2="value">
        <ns3:tag-3 attrib3="value">blabla</ns3:tag-3>
    </ns2:tag-2>
</ns1:tag-1>
```

test.py

```
import xmltodict as x2d
with open('ESCIDOC_test.xml', encoding='utf-8') as purein:
    doc = x2d.parse(purein.read())
print(doc['ns1:tag-1']['ns2:tag-2']['@attrib2'])  # works
print(doc['ns1:tag-1']['ns2:tag-2']['ns3:tag-3']['#text'] # does not work, TypeError
ns3tree = doc['ns1:tag-1']['ns2:tag-2']['ns3:tag-3'] 
print(ns3tree['#text'])  # works
```

Why do I need to assign it to a new variable first, to make it work? The whole xml is parsed anyway, isn't it?

```
print(doc)
# OrderedDict([('ns1:tag-1', OrderedDict([('ns2:tag-2', OrderedDict([('@attrib1', 'value'), ('@attrib2', 'value'), ('ns3:tag-3', OrderedDict([('@attrib3', 'value'), ('#text', 'blabla')]))]))]))])
```

Is this intended because of possible memory issues? Is there a more elegant workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left out the closing ) on the line that does not work.

I used python 3.5, copied your files but added the closing ) and changed ESCIDOC_test.xml to test.xml. Ran it and all 3 print statements worked correctly (no TypeError).

Comment: Depending on whether this answer is correct (I haven't tested myself), this is probably the best first post I've reviewed.

Comment: It's official: your solution is correct. This is the best first post I've reviewed.